# Angular 8 Data-table

Tags: angular

I'm upgrading a project from Angular5 to Angular8. In this project angular5-data-table was used to manage data-table.The lib has been upgraded many times for Angular4, 5 and 7 but not for Angular8.Is there an equivalent I can use with code similarity ?

Thank you.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular5-data-table

Comment: If you use Angular Material, then MatTable is what you want